How to predict unlabels text data with predict_generator in keras?
I am trying to perform prediction on my NPL model using predict_generator, my test data does not have a Y variable. My purpose is to predict labels on future texts. I have tried 'Y_test=None' inside the generator, it gives me a positional error. I have also tried to predict using model.predict(X_test), that also did not work. I am looking for help to resolve this issue. See my code below, any suggestion is wolcome.
train_generator = generator (X_train,Y_train,tokenizer,onehot,label_encoder, n_classes,batch_size)
validation_generator = generator (X_valid,Y_valid,tokenizer,onehot,label_encoder, n_classes,batch_size)
test_generator = generator (X_test,Y_test,tokenizer,onehot,label_encoder, n_classes,batch_size)

model.predict_generator(test_generator)


I finally realized that I do not need to use generator for test data, I just used the tokenizer to transform X_train then use model.predict(X_train) and I am able to predict labels.
